# Getting an error in php5.6 not in php5.5

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-5.5, php-5.6

I'm trying to get a phpdaemon running on ubuntu 16.04 with php5.6. 
It runs on ubuntu 1404 with php5.5.9. I tried google of course but I don't know php code at all.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /../../Service.php on line 79
```

This is the the actual code on line 79 an a bit below:

```
            if(array_key_exists("session_id", $createSession)) {
            // Session ID.
            $sessionId = $createSession["session_id"];
```

Would be great if someone could help me out.

EDIT:
thanks for the quick replies. someone asked for the $createsession. I think this is it, but I am not sure.
still, I'm not sure why it runs on the old version.

```
            // Create and invoke.
        $createSession = $this->call_service(P_XMLRPC_URL, "create_session", array(
            "requester" => $sale['prkcode'] . '#' . $sale['pdcode'],
            "service" => P_SERVICE,
            "version" => P_VERSION,
            "invoke" => array(
                "method" => PRM_INVOKE_METHOD,
                "parameters" => array(
                    "tickets" => array(
                        $ticket
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
```

Comment: Just **read** the error - `$createSession` is `null` instead of `array`

Comment: Can you find the part of the code where `$createSession` is created?

Comment: @AlonEitan I agree it's an easy error to understand but it doesn't answer why it works in `5.5` and not `5.6`.

Comment: the failure is not on this line, maybe another part of your code which sets your `$createSession` isn't working! The `array_key_exists` has two params since the function exists.

Comment: @Albzi I don't know - Perhaps another function use to return array and now returning `null` and the OP save it to `$createSession`. But really - If they come to ask us a question, they should at least show us all the relevant parts of their code

Comment: I absolutely agree with you @AlonEitan :) That's why I've asked for more information. However we haven't got it so voting to close.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.I added the info you requested It think.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Unfortunately, still there is not enough information as it now opens up to other bits of code. `call_service`, `P_XMLRPC_URL` and other variables/functions we don't know about pop up here. Your best bet here is to get someone to properly look at it.

Comment: Ok I will have someone look at it then. And for now I'll run it on the old system. Thanks for the quick responses everyone. I will close the question now.